# how can I syncronize with mvvm?

Tags: android, android-mvvm

I'm studying mvvm. When I call init(), the first call is null.
using retrofit, I think the reason is that the function `getIndexRetrofit()` is returned before the line execute `data.value = res`. So I wanna syncronize this, expecting the function to return not null but the response values.

**Repository:**

```
fun getIndexRetrofit(name:String) : MutableLiveData<UserModel>{   

    Retrofit2Service.getService().requestUserInfo(name).enqueue(object: Callback<UserModel> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<UserModel>, t: Throwable) {
           data.postValue(null)
        }
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<UserModel>, response: Response<UserModel>) {
            if(response.body()!=null) {
                var res = response.body()!!

                data.value = res
            }
        }
    })//Retrofit

    return data
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code? Try logging `Log.e(TAG, $t)` the error in `onFailure()`

Comment: Please also paste your viewmodel code from where this repository function is called. And from where are you calling `init()`? Lastlycould you paste the logcat output of the `null` value that you are receiving

Comment: Is `getIndexRetrofit()` part of ViewModel ? If so then do what I've mentioned in answer below + observe data from view model `viewModel.data.observe(this) { ... }` inside your activity or fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say what `getIndexRetrofit()` suppose to do, but I believe you are misusing live data here. You are making asynchronous call `Retrofit2Service.getService().requestUserInfo(name).enqueue` It will be called, request will be made, but the result of execution is not yet received, at the same time `return data` will happen.

Understand that `onFailure()` and `onResponse()` are callbacks, and the code will not be executed immediately. You code is not meant to be read sequentially top to bottom. Sequence of execution will be next

1. `Retrofit2Service.getService().requestUserInfo(name).enqueue`
2. `return data`
3. `onResponse()` or `onFailure()`

You should not return anything in `getIndexRetrofit()` instead refactor your function to look like that

```
fun getIndexRetrofit(name:String) {   
    Retrofit2Service.getService().requestUserInfo(name).enqueue(object: Callback<UserModel> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<UserModel>, t: Throwable) {
           data.postValue(null)
        }
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<UserModel>, response: Response<UserModel>) {
            if(response.body()!=null) {
                var res = response.body()!!
                data.value = res
            }
        }
    })
}
```